# Gradle doesn't import libraries in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I am studying how to use Gradle in Intellij IDEA to import necessary libraries automatically (in Java projects). I created new clean project on Gradle, added dependencies in file 'build.gradle', added imports in file 'Main.java', but libraries aren't imported and errors occure. I expect that Gradle should load libraries from Maven Repository automatically, but it doesn't happen.

I created new project in Intellij IDEA (file/new/project - on Java, Gradle and 'Groovy' in 'Gradle DSL'). In the file 'gradle-wrapper.properties' I successfully updated Gradle to version 8.0.2 (because by default IDEA uses the 7th version and then says that it is incompatible with JDK19).

Then I added dependencies into 'build.gradle' file:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    testImplementation (
            "com.codeborne:selenide:6.3.5",
            "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.8.2")
}
```

And added imports into 'Main.java':

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import static com.codeborne.selenide.Condition.text;
import static com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide.$;
import static com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide.open;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
        Selenide.open("https://www.google.com/");
    }
}
```

I clicked "Reload all Gradle projects" and it said:
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 780ms

But imports didn't happen, I can't run 'Main.java'. When I click "Build project", it says:

```
C:\IT\Projects\CheckingGradle\src\main\java\org\example\Main.java:2: error: package org.junit.jupiter.api does not exist
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

failed
:compileJava
Main.java
package org.junit.jupiter.api does not exist
package com.codeborne.selenide does not exist
and so on
```

I expected that Gradle should load necessary libraries from Maven Repository, but it doesn't happen.

The project on the Github: https://github.com/Anton248/CheckingGradle

When I make a project without Gradle and add libraries manually, all works fine (https://github.com/Anton248/Study2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have specified your dependencies as test dependencies (which these libraries typically are), but the code which tries to use these libraries is in *main*. Tests and other code using test dependencies should be put in `src/test/java`, not in `src/main/java`.

Alternatively, you need to declare your dependencies as normal (*main*) dependencies (e.g. using `implementation` instead of `testImplementation`).

Answer (score 1):

On my `IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1` Gradle based project, just changing `testImplementation` to `implementation` for `org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.9.2` solved the issue.

This is despite the described error occurring (before the fix) in java file under `src/test/java/` (where `testImplementation` should suffice).

Looks like even the latest & greatest `IntelliJ IDEA 2023` is not bug-free.